# No cached version of 3.6.0 available for offline

Tags: java, android, gradle

1. org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
2. org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0.
3. org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0 available for offline mode.
   In 3rd option, I tried Gradle click File > Settings (on a Mac, Android Studio > Preferences) to open the Settings dialog.

In the left pane, expand Build, Execution, Deployment and then click Gradle.

Under Global Gradle settings, UNCHECK the Offline work checkbox.
Click Apply or OK for your changes to take effect.

But no in Gradle Global Gradle setting didn't found.  what should I do?

Comment: Are you working without internet connection in your system?

Comment: Could you possibly post the content of your Gradle file and screenshots of what is going wrong?
There is not really a lot that can be fetched from your description.

Answer (score 1):

How to disable offline mode in AndroidStudio 3.6: 
select View > Tool Windows > Gradle. Then, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel